# get custom result from MySQL based table

Tags: mysql, join, max, min

[image] I am confused that how I can retrieve following results from given table (Snapshot Attached)

I want all the  course (Disnict), dept, school, Min(semester), Max(semester) form table subjects

Needed Result:

subid  | school |  dept |  course | minSemester  | MaxSemester  |

Comment: Where did you got confused? Explain clearly what error are you gettting?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
       t.subid ,
       t.school, 
       t.dept,
       t.course, 
       min(t1.semester),
       max(t1.semester)
FROM table t, table t1
WHERE 
    t1.school  =  t.school
AND t1.dept    =  t.dept 
AND t1.course  =  t.subid 

GROUP BY t.subid ,t.school, t.dept, t.course
```